# Specified Web Pages version “3.0.0.0” could not be found. Update your web.config to specify a different version. Current version: “2.0.0.0”

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have this problem in my web service:

> Specified Web Pages version “3.0.0.0” could not be found. Update your
>   web.config to specify a different version. Current version: “2.0.0.0”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/3.0.0) nuget package by entering this line in package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages -Version 3.0.0
```

Or find and install it using Nuget Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Nuget Package Manager` in `Visual Studio Code`. Search for `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` and `update` this package if you already have the latest one the you should try to `downgrade` one version previous.

Or

You can run the below command in `Package Manager Console` in `Visual Studio`:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
```

This will resolve the issue.